# LaTeX new command with no argument

Tags: beamer, macros

I write some presentation with beamer. In the middle between each section I create some frame for outline content. But because presentation too long, I used `\includeonlyframes{current}` command to shorten compilation time, so  some part of that frame will be visible and other not visible. For simplicity, I set `\newcommand{}` to that frame (outline frame). Now, how to set some of that frame available after compilation and other not visible.  I mean how to call command with no argument. For example I create command

```
\newcommand{\current}[1]{\begin{frame}
[label=#1]
\frametitle{Outline}
\tableofcontents[currentsection , hideothersubsections ]
\end{frame}}
```

And I will call that command with no argument like `\current` for section that beyond my current editing, becasued I need some of that frame will not visible. I just need to show frame that related with my current editing (current section).

Answer (score 2):

```
\newcommand\current[1][]{%
  \ifx\relax#1\relax\else
    \begin{frame}[label=#1]
      \frametitle{Outline}
      \tableofcontents[currentsection , hideothersubsections ]
    \end{frame}%
  \fi}
```

Will use the frame only for `\current[something]` but *not* for `\current` or `\current[]`